# Is it correct to use Al-Haj before the name of persons who completed their haj?

Tags: sunnah, terminology, hajj, bidah

I saw most of the Muslims who have completed their Hajj add the prefix `Al-Haj` or `Haji`to their names, like adding `Al-Hafiz` to those who finished memorizing the whole Al-Quran.

> **Haji** is an honorific title given to a Muslim person who has successfully completed the Hajj to Mecca. Women who complete the Hajj
>   are referred to as **Hajiya** - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hajji)

Is it a sunnah or bid'ah?

Comment: Bidat is when one change a law of Islam. to be Bidat you first should show the original law of Islam and then show it has changed. is there any law banning using this title?

Comment: @BattleofKarbala, But what I heard from scholars is Bidah means any new innovations which are not in Islam. Changing the law of Islam is Haram. Is it correct?

Comment: any new innovation is not Bidat. claiming new law in Islam is Bidat. for example using airplane or mobile phone is not Bidat. there are different scholars with different beliefs. Bidat is Haram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No brother it's not Bid'ah and not Sunnah. It's a title given to travelers for Hajj, so if you are going to Hajj and I meet you in your way to Hajj I can call you Hajji also you can use it as a title before your name if you has successfully completed the Hajj to Mecca like you said.

But **it's not bid'ah** because it's just a recipe Arab people used to use it from long time, Just like when I use Al-Hafiz to call the  person who finished memorizing the whole Quran, when I use Al-Qari to call the person who read the Quran, when I use Imam to call the leader of a mosque and Muslim community, when I use Shahid to call person who died fighting for Allah Subhanahu wa ta'ala and when I write "Al-Sahabe" before the name of the person who saw the Prophet Mohammad peace be upon him and believed him.

And by the way:
The meaning of Hajj **in Arabic language** can be: "The come" or "pilgrimage" or "intent".
And the meaning of Hajji **in Arabic language** can be: "The comer" or "The pilgrim".

And Allah knows best, Wa salla Allah ala Mohammad.

Answer (score 1):

It's neither bed'a nor sun'a. It is more of honorable name & it can be even used to call those who never been to Hajj to honor them.

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. This would be a good answer if you could elaborate more. I'm guessing it's more of a cultural thing though.